# On the Jacobian Conjecture

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I have been asked to do a work on the [Jacobian Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture) for my master's course. While I am familirized with that conjecture and I understand its implications, I would like to ask you all if there is any book you can recommend me about it. I'd prefer it to be in english, but spanish, italian, french or portuguese are welcome too.

This work is set in the background of algebraic geometry, so if the book you may recommend also sets in this background, then it's best, but it is not strictly necessary.

Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for any reference, but I would recommend the following:
Arno van den Essen, ``Polynomial Automorphisms and the Jacobian Conjecture'' - Birkhäuser Verlag 2000

As far as I know the book's out of print, but it can still be found on the internet.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Actually, I presented my work, which achieved to contain enough references and information on the conjecture, being the one you mention one of them.

Comment: I don't see any option for personal messages on this site, unfortunately, but you managed to interest me, actually. That is, I wrote my master's thesis on a subject related to the Jacobian Conjecture a few months ago. And the superviser _was_ Arno van den Essen. You may see why I'd like to know what you did. In case you're interested in what I did, there múst be an option to communicate outside stackexchange...

Comment: You may refer to my e-mail address on my profile, but my work was just more like information gathering than anything serious. It is pretty basic and I hardly doubt that it contains anything that might interest you.